# Difference in coefficient estimates

Tags: statistics, regression

I have simple regression $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\epsilon$. Then I have estimates $\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta_1}$ computed from n observation and estimates $\beta_0',\beta_1'$ computed from n+1 observations. I am asked to derive the difference in those two estimates as a function of sample statistics. I am not even sure how to begin. I started with $\hat{\beta_1}-\beta_1'$ and plugging in $\hat{\beta_1}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i(x_i-\bar{x})}$ and $\beta_1'=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i(x_i-\bar{x})}$ but I couldn't make anything sensible out of this.

Comment: What simplification are you seeking?  Is the desired result permitted to have terms $x_{n+1}$ and $y_{n+1}$ embedded?

Comment: Start at the very beginning. If you know $\bar X_n$ is the average of $X_1, \dots, X_n$ and you know $X_{n+1}$, how do you express the average $\bar X_{n+1}$ of the first $n+1$ observations in terms of $\bar X_n$  and $X_{n+1}.$ I won't say more because I don't know the level at which you are working. (For regression diagnostics, one often wants the reverse of this. Knowing the coefficients for all $n$ observations, and feeling one of them might be an outlier, what would the line look like without that suspicious observation.)

Comment: @Dr. MV I am not entirely sure,  but I suppose it is permitted.

Comment: @Bruce Trumbo Thank you for hint,  I will try to use it and see where it will lead me.